# How to include LocalDB with project when built?

Tags: c#, ado.net, localdb

First of all, I am still very new to LocalDB and to ADO.NET as a whole, so if this is a stupid question (and it probably is, knowing me and new material), I apologize.

I am building a .NET 5 console application, and using ADO.NET to connect it to a LocalDB database.  There have been a few snags, though.  First of all, I have to double-click the database file in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer (I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community Preview) in order for the app to be able to see the database.  This was a mild annoyance when I was doing internal testing, but now that that's done, I can't expect all of my users to have Visual Studio.

Second, I currently have the database connection string as an absolute path:

```
 static string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=P:\\PROJECTS\\NACS-TRACKER\\DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
```

Obviously, this won't work any more now that I'm ready to have others test the app.  Given that I'm new to this, I don't really know if relative paths would be appropriate here.  If so, how would I go about doing it?

Finally, how would I make sure that the database file is included with the build?  Thanks!

Comment: Get the LocalDB standalone installer and package it with your app. Install it silently, and attach your database to it as part of the install.

Comment: I use [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MartinCostello.SqlLocalDb/) to ensure a localDB to exist. So if you build your project, include the mdf/ldf in your solution - maybe via some Postbuild Event and attach the database to localDB on application start (hopefully I got your request right)